# REST ajax request is being invoked every 5 minutes | weblogic

Tags: java, ajax, web-services, rest, weblogic-10.x

I am facing this problem when a rest webservice is being invoked by my UI code running on weblogic 10.3.0, after precisely 5 minutes the webservice gets invoked again. Am puzzled as to where the problem is.

My request is coming from Ajax call on ExtJS UI. This request hits the backend webservice which typically consumes more than 5 minutes. So as soon as time from first request surpasses 5 minute duration there is another webservice hit (as per the logs). I checked the network using firebug but i dont see multiple requests.

At first I thought this might be the ajax timeout,  so tried setting the global timeout in ajax as 2 hrs but that isnt helping. 
I configured web.xml session timeout as 2 hrs which dint help either. 
In weblogic admin console i tried the max timeout for JTA (java transaction API) (assuming its something to do with all transactions) to 1800 seconds, which also dint help.

I would much appreciate it if you guys give me some pointers as to what other things I can try to resolve this issue.

PS: Its 5 minutes to the exact second as per the logs.

```
2016-12-13 07:52:25,783 INFO [103' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] search.Search.exportData - Starting exportData
2016-12-13 07:57:25,787 INFO ['72' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] search.Search.exportData - Starting exportData
2016-12-13 08:02:25,784 INFO [101' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] search.Search.exportData - Starting exportData
```

The problem is that my webservice is getting invoked every 5 minutes iff the duration of that webservice goes beyond 5 minutes.  Let me explain it with an example:

```
@ Time 0 minutes : UI calls a webservice : /exportData  (lets say this api typically takes 16 minutes to complete)
@ Time 5th minute : /exportData gets invoked again with no interation from UI. Nor there is a trace in UI network which says UI called this webservice.
@ Time 10th minute : /exportData gets invoked again
@ Time 15th minute : /exportData gets invoked again
```

So in the end at minute 15.1  , there will be 4 instances of exportData running parallel. I have tried to increase the timeout in ajax request and session timeout in web.xml and other things but none of it is resolving the issue.

If the exportData happen to finish within 5 minute, there wont be any subsequent invocations. The problem is that application should not re invoke the webservice if that particular call takes more than 5 minutes, I just wish to find out where this timeout of 5 minutes is configured.

I have already tried setting that ajax.timeout globally to 2 hrs, web.xml session timeout to 2hrs. Changed weblogic JTA timeout to 30 minutes. But it hasnt helped.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the problem is. Are you trying to figure out what code is calling the webservice? Are you trying to figure out why it takes 5 minutes for the request to complete? Can you modify your question and put an actual question at the end of it and and a restatement of what you think the problem is?

Comment: Hi Brian, I have updated the problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

A few things come to mind... if you are sure it's your webapp making the calls, use Firebug or Chrome dev tools and put a breakpoint at the point it calls your webservice, then use the stack trace to backtrack and figure out what's triggering it (presumably every 5 minutes).

I'm assuming a few things here... is the call to the webservice juts kicking off a job and it doesn't need the results?

I think what you might want to do is put something in the server side code that keeps track if an export is already running and when a call comes into the webservice, it first checks to see if it's already running and if so, it doesn't run it again. If the webapp does look at the results, your webservice could just return a message like "export already running."

Comment: Hi Brian, on completion of exportData api, it will push back a downloadable Excel file. I think the above approach might not work for me, because this API might be called multiple times by different browser sessions by users in which case it would return complaining export is already in progress but the behaviour should be that it should process multiple requests simultaneously. Althought i can maintain a session ID as unique id static data and compare but same browser - new tab will provide same session ID

Comment: Ah. Ok, that's good info to know (you should have put that in the question :) )... ok, another idea... write the exported Excel to a file locally. When a request comes in to export it, just serve up the Excel file on the file system. You can have your own process server side that updates the file on a regular basis (every 5 minutes, 30 minutes, whatever), so no matter who requests the export, they will get a file immediately.

Comment: I am already writing the content to a temporary file on system. But the problem is i wont be able to differentiate between a repeat hit from same browser tab or a new request hit from another tab(browser tab) as session ID would be the same so the API might consider the new request as repeat request and serve a wrong file.

Comment: I assumed the file was the same for everyone - are you saying it's different depending on who asks for it?

Comment: Yes file will be different based on the parameters it receives. Based on the params it will fetch content from database and constructs a spreadsheet which is returned to the invoked user.